# Magento Login Issues

Tags: php, function, magento, var

Currently we run our website through Magento, however we seem to have an issue with logins. We figured out that something keeps changing the permissions on one of the folders in the "var" directory, but we're not too sure what to do to fix this.

The error we get is:

```
Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'ERR' in /home/ezycare/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 0
```

Would anyone know what might fix this issue?

Comment: As far as I know ERR is a constant, in Zend_Log class (lib/Zend/Log.php), so, look threw last code changes

Answer (score 0):

Please download the given file and place it on root folder and run on browser.

```
https://github.com/IndiesServices/Magento/blob/master/magento-cleanup.php
```

This will help you to setup the file and folder permissions for magento.